# Applying the right-hand rule for magnetic forces

Tags: forces, vectors, magnetic-fields

I am confused about the [right-hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) for the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). I am using same method as Brightstorm.com is:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LK7hv4LX3ys

But for some reason it does not match op with this example from my book.

[image: Right hand rule exampld]

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

I first curl my finger around the wire so as the current is going downwards.

But since the charge is moving upwards, I need to flip my hand upwards, but that flips the curl, and thereby the direction of the $B$-field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that the charge is negative!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with equation $F=v \times B$ I visualize the vector v pointing up, and traveling (rotating) the shortest arc to the B vector, which is pointing into the page, v and B now define a plane. The direction the vector v takes is counter-clockwise or clockwise depending on what side of the plane you are looking at, so I visualize a right-handed screw along that normal axis (that vector F will lie along) and imagine what direction that screw will travel if it turns along with vector v. Then in your case you have a negative charge which changes the sign of F. I'm sure there are many different and more elegant ways to calculate it, but that is what I think of to double-check.